# Booting encrypted partition after changing encryption password

Tags: boot, encryption, hp

Recently I recieved a HP laptop with encrypted ubuntu 22.04.1 after changing password every time I boot after few seconds of loading screen with writing ,,Protected by HP sure start" and ubuntu logo below it instead for being asked for a password like before initramfs console shows up and I have to type:
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p3 temp
(I have to type password)
exit
after that everything works fine How can I fix that?